# How to select elements (using jQuery) that have the class attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following elements:

```
<div class="some-name-1"></div>
<div class="some-name-2"></div>
<div class="some-name-3"></div>
<div class="other-name-1"></div>
<div class="other-name-2"></div>
```

I need next elements:

```
<div class="some-name-1"></div>
<div class="some-name-2"></div>
<div class="some-name-3"></div>
```

I tested `jQuery('class^="some-name-"')`, but that does not work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `class^="some-name-"` is an invalid selector. If you meant to use the attribute-starts-with selector, you have to enclose it in `[]`, as described in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/). FYI, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code to learn how to format code. Don't trouble yourself encoding any characters.

Comment: @Felix Kling - thanks a million! It was very simple :)

Comment: @Somnath: If you edit the question, make sure it does look worse as before. You didn't convert `&lt;` to `<` or removed the `</code>` and `<br>` tags. I would not have approved your edit.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks next time i will take care of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [] in that selector.

```
jQuery('div[class^="some-name-"]')
```

try that

Answer (score 4):

You just need to enclose the `class^="some-name-"` in square brackets: [^ in Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$('[class^="some-name-"]')
```

I'm pretty sure that will work.